# How to initialize variables in while loops

Tags: vimscript

In `C` you can do something like this:

```
int foo(int a) { return a + 1; }
int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    while ((a = foo(a)) < 10) {
        /* */
    }
}
```

How can I do the same thing in vimscript, i.e. something like this:

```
function! s:foo()
    let l:foo = 0
    while (let l:foo = l:foo + 1) < 10)
        echo 'hi'
    endwhile
endfunction
```

i.e. I want to make the while loop dependent on a value that is assigned anew with every loop. You could do this with traditional for or do-while loops, but sadly Vimscript doesn't have these. One way I see how you can do this is, is like this:

```
function! s:foo()
    let l:foo = 0

    while l:foo + 1 < 10
        let l:foo = l:foo + 1
        echo 'hi'
    endwhile
endfunction
```

But if the operation is expensive and you need to make more than one comparison (*is it equal to 5, 7, or 12*, *etc*), this gets ridiculous pretty quickly.

There must be a better way to do this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.  Every line in the script is the same as running it in the command window (e.g. `:while 1 | echo 'hi' | endwhile`).  The `:while` command evaluates a boolean/numeric expression to the right of it, and `:let` is a command that defines a variable.  Commands don't return a value.

The `for...endfor` loop is the only loop that I know of that will create variables if you're iterating over a sequence, like `for i in range(10)`.

If your loop condition is really going to be complicated you could use an indefinite loop and break when your condition is met:

```
let foo = 0

while 1
  if foo + 1 >= 10 || s:other_condition()
    break
  endif
  let foo += 1
  echo 'hi'
endwhile
```

Or

```
let done = 0
let foo = 1

while !done
  let foo += 1
  echo 'hi'
  let done = foo + 1 > 10 || s:other_condition()
endwhile
```

IMO, both are the equivalent of what you're wanting to accomplish.  Except that in the second one, you can't thoughtlessly `continue` from anywhere in the body.